# Resizing of multiple images through scripts

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is there any option to badge multiple images in size 60x60 in png format I know it is done through file>scripts>image processor but it gives the output images in jpg not png how to format in png

Comment: I didn't even know about the "image processor" function in Photoshop. So useful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own photoshop action that does this. Create a new action in the action panel, then open one image as an example, then crop and scale the image to the right size, then save the resulting cropped image as a png. Then stop recording your actions. You can then batch edit an entire folder (or custom selection) of images using that action. They'll all save as PNGs if that is how you set the action to save them. If you've not used the action panel before I can provide more instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for an updated version of the Image Processor JSX script.

I did and found this one:
**Image Processor CS4 PNG**
http://www.ps-scripts.com/bb/viewtopic.php?t=3149 (not available anymore)

Direct download:
Copy [Image Processor PNG.jsx](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o6mifq8ldd64coz/Image%20Processor%20PNG.jsx?dl=0) to *[Photoshop application folder] / Presets / Scripts*

Credits:
Added PNG-24 support 11/10/2009 by Mike Hale

It was made for CS4 but Photoshop CC accepts this script, too.
Give it a try.

Comment: Hi Mario. I tried the link, it sends me to a GoDaddy parking page:
"Welcome to: ps-scripts.com
This Web page is parked for FREE, courtesy of GoDaddy.com." (I just wanted to try the script myself)

Comment: You are right, the page does not exist anymore. I will search for an alternative source. Thx

Comment: Awesome, man. Thanks :') I'm sure others are interested as well.