# I have few PNG files, I want to make them same size and same dimension, how to do it in simple way?

Tags: information-graphics

I have few PNG files, I want to make them same size and same dimension, how to do it in simple way ?I dont have any software related to graphics on my laptop. pls guide.

Comment: You'll need to get some software, like Photohsop or the free software GIMP(dot)org - i.e. software which can edit raster images, and the PNG format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resizing of multiple images through scripts](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/53546/resizing-of-multiple-images-through-scripts)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't really graphics design related but if you wanted to do that you could use these links to software and sites:

1. https://www.gimp.org/
2. https://pixlr.com/
3. https://www.picmonkey.com/
4. https://www.befunky.com/
5. https://www.fotor.com/

These are the best online and downloadable *FREE* photo editors hopefully these should help!